# What is the fastest way of obtaining a tourist visa for Canada as an Australian resident?

Tags: visas, canada, australia, south-africa

I am a South African living in South Australia with my Australian partner on a defacto partner visa bridging A and B. We are going on a family holiday through the USA through to Canada and then onto Hawaii before heading back home, its all booked and paid for. our travel agent has made a mistake and I do not have a visa to get into  Canada and we leave for America on the 18th of March, I have an appointment to get my American visa on the 9th of march in Melbourne. Do you have any advise on how to obtain an Canadian visa in the short amount of time we have?

Comment: Have you started the [online process](http://onlineservices-servicesenligne.cic.gc.ca/eapp/eapp.do)? You might just make it if you start your app immediately.

Answer (score 1):

First you should complete the online eligibility survey. It will give you a reference code you can use to apply online for a visa.
http://www.cic.gc.ca/ctc-vac/getting-started.asp
You'll use this to apply for your your visitor's visa. Applying online is marginally faster than going through an embassy/consulate.  **The processing time for 80% of cases at the time of writing is 20 days**.
More info on processing times: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/index.asp

NOTE: Even people from visa-exempt countries still need to apply for an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA). Your partner will likely need to apply for this as well. This is very quick, most take a few minutes online for approval.
http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta-form-help.asp